# Conky/Dzen2 Clickable Areas

Tags: conky

I'm trying for the first time to use dzen on my setup, then on the Arch Wiki I came up with the section about clickable areas, to pipe the command into conky and then when I click the text on conky the dzen2 script would show up.

But the command on conky simply doesn't work. I tried writing every way but it doesn't. The wiki says the following:

> Save this script and make it executable and then use the ^ca()
>   attribute in your conkyrc (or the script that you pipe to dzen2) to
>   trigger it.
>
> ^ca(1,)Sysinfo^ca()

But it does nothing. When I replace the path to my script it just shows this command in form of a conky text. If I execute my script on terminal it runs correctly, but this command on conky does nothing at all.

Comment: Just to clarify... You included the path to your script in the `^ca()` attribute added to conky, so it's `^ca(1,<path to your script>)Sysinfo^ca()`, as noted at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dzen#Clickable_areas_and_popups, right?

Comment: This way it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case it was caused by installing it from [some fork](https://github.com/minos-org/dzen2) (actually, it's first page that is searched by google under **dzen2**).

Installing from [robm github](https://github.com/robm/dzen) made it work.